# jQuery select parent then other div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a function that adds/removes classes with onclick but I can't get it to work.

What I'm trying to do is: when I click on the `<a data-toggle- xxxx>` I want to get the panel group I've clicked on with `$('.panel-group a').click()` and remove class TURN and TURNN on the `$(this)` and add it again when clicked on again if it doens't have that class.

But the `$(this).find('.linker)` is not selecting `.linker` or `.rechter`

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-group">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#{{vraag.vraag}}">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title" style="margin: 0;">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" id="hasclass" href="#{{vraag.vraag}}">
                        <h3>{{vraag.vraag}}</h3>
                        <h6 class="linker TURN">|</h6>
                        <h6 class="rechter TURNN">|</h6>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="{{vraag.vraag}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body-tekst">
                    <h6>{{vraag.tekstblok}}</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('.panel-group a').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find('#hasclass').find('.rechter').removeClass('TURN');
        $(this).parent().find('#hasclass').find('.linker').removeClass('TURNN');
    });
});
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid as you have nested `a` elements. Also note you have the `TURN` and `TURNN` classes the wrong way around

Comment: Also you could just write `$(this).find('.rechter,.linker').removeClass('TURN TURNN')`

Comment: true but exept the jquery, all works fine

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan true and @RamonDeVries try using `toggleclass` function after a is not nested anymore

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ye the nested one is needed for the clickable dropdown, but i want to make sure the whole thing is clickable and not only the text inside

Comment: looks like your code has the `TURN` and `TURNN` mixed up. `.retcher` has `TURNN` but you're trying to remove `TURN`

Comment: @RamondeVries You don't need an `<a>` to make something "clickable" in `jQuery`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen the a is not for jquery clickable, its the `href="#{{vraag.vraag}}"` that i need

Comment: It's still invalid HTML which will cause issues in other area, most notably accessibility. In any case the problem is a simple typo, you're removing the wrong class from `linker` and `rechter`.

Comment: @RamondeVries well you have 2 `<a>` one inside the other and they both have `href="#{{vraag.vraag}}"` kinda dont see why you have the second  then

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen that's from the original bootstrap code, maybe i can change that `a` to a `div`

Comment: @RamondeVries well as Rory says it's still invalid HTML and if you read the other comments, you are remove the wrong class from the wrong elements. Aka the problem is a simple type error from your side

Comment: I've got it sorted ty guys. `if ($(this).parent().find('#hasclass').find('.linker').hasClass('TURN')){
            $(this).parent().find('#hasclass').find('.linker').removeClass('TURN');
        }else{
            $(this).parent().find('#hasclass').find('.linker').addClass('TURN');
        }
        if($(this).parent().find('#hasclass').find('.rechter').hasClass('TURNN')){
            $(this).parent().find('#hasclass').find('.rechter').removeClass('TURNN');
        }else{
            $(this).parent().find('#hasclass').find('.rechter').addClass('TURNN');
        }`

Comment: I'd suggest you cache those selectors. You can make the code much less verbose and quicker. You can also make it simpler by just using `toggleClass()`. All that code can be turned in to just this: http://jsfiddle.net/wg3dsrqx/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if i would have 1 function running `toggleClass()`, it returns 0 and 1's in the background. since i have multiple of these `panel-groups`, when I open one and click the other one it wants to close that one even tho that one isn't open.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The logic of the fiddle I posted is identical to the block of code in your previous comment

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.panel-group a').off().on('click', function() {
    debugger
    let $this = $(this).parents('.panel-group');
    if ($this.find('.linker').hasClass('TURN')) {
        $this.find('.linker').removeClass('TURN');
    } else {
        $this.find('.linker').addClass('TURN');
    }
    if ($this.find('.rechter').hasClass('TURNN')) {
        $(this).find('.rechter').removeClass('TURNN');
    } else {
        $(this).find('.rechter').addClass('TURNN');
    }
});
```